# How to trigger manually mat-checkbox change event

Tags: angular-material

I have hidden `mat-checkbox` which is binded to formControl and I need to trigger this formControl change while clicking on some icon (which is supposed to be binded to checkbox). But I can't figure out how to trigger manually that change event. Unfortunatelly `.toggle()` method of mat-chechbox doesn't change my formControl value and doesn't trigger change event

```
    <mat-checkbox [hidden] #availabilityCheckbox (change)="toggleInputs(i)" formControlName="available"></mat-checkbox>      
    <mat-icon
      (click)="availabilityCheckbox.toggle()"
      class="variants-action-icon m-r-1"
    >
      {{ variationsFormArray.controls[i].get('available').value ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off' }}
    </mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case please try out this,

```
<mat-icon
  (click)="availabilityCheckbox._onInputClick($event)"
  class="variants-action-icon m-r-1"
>
  {{ variationsFormArray.controls[i].get('available').value ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off' }}
</mat-icon>
```

Actually `_onInputClick($event)` is the event we need to call on checkbox template reference. It will trigger the `(change)` event.

Answer (score 0):

if you use reactive form, use it

variationsFormArray.controls[i]?.get('available')?.setValue(!variationsFormArray.controls[i]?.get('available')?.value);

it would be better to extract this in a function it your ts